# Boost multiprecision fails because the implementation of complex tries to cast to double in internal functions like _Isinf or _Isnan

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2012, complex-numbers, arbitrary-precision

I need a BSD-like licensed C(++) multiprecision library with complex numbers support so I tried boost.

The following code fails:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <complex>

using namespace boost::multiprecision;    
std::complex<cpp_dec_float_50>(1.0, 2.0) / std::complex<cpp_dec_float_50>(1.0, 2.0)
```

in Visual Studio 2012 with an error C2440 because the implementation of complex tries to cast to double in internal functions like _Isinf or _Isnan.

Is this an error on my part? How can I fix this? Are there better libraries?

Answer (score 3):

From C++11 26.4/2:

> The effect of instantiating the template complex for any type other
>   than float, double, or long double is unspecified.

So you can't reliably use `std::complex` with other types, but perhaps boost has a `complex` type that works with `cpp_dec_float_50`.

Comment: Afaik boost only has some extensions to std::complex in tr1/complex.hpp but no replacement.

Answer (score 1):

GCC 4.7 will allow you to use boost multiprecision floats with `std::complex<>`.